# Nginx returns 400 for a proxy_pass to an external URL

Tags: nginx

I am trying to have a route in my Nginx which will proxy the request to an external https resource. My config for that looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name x.x.com;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://y.y.com$request_uri;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I try to call the URL I will immediately get a 400.

Strangely enough on the Nginx logs, I will not get any reason for the 400 at first. Only after exactly 1 minute, I will get a timeout message. (My error log level is set to info)

```
nginx_1_e6b52cd440fd | 999.999.99.999 - - [29/Aug/2019:10:05:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 226 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1_e6b52cd440fd | 2019/08/29 10:06:27 [info] 67#67: *30 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while waiting for request, client: 999.999.99.999, server: 0.0.0.0:8080
```

My Nginx is running as a docker container using Nginx:1.17

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing a similar issue I solved it in the end by adding

```
proxy_set_header Host y.y.com;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

For some reason the server did not like the request having the default x.x.com host  header and rejected it with a 400, which probably comes from some webserver configuration on the serverside.